# Is it possible to store 2 separate values within one variable? PYTHON

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to make a budget programme and wanted to store a variable with an integer value and also a string for example: Car - £200.

I made a line of code using "and" which allows me to input a string value and then the price value but it only saves as the price value so when I print later on in the code it only shows values no description.

See below the code that I used.

```
EXPENSE1 = input("Expense name: ") and int(input("Expense value: "))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use python dictionaries.

```
my_dict = dict()

key = input("Enter the key: ")
value = input("Enter the value: ")

my_dict[key] = value
```